# Machinist + Cabybara + Test::Unit = blueprints missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, machinist

I've run into a very confusing problem...

All my tests pass when i run them in isolation.
When I run them like rake test, after my integration tests run, Machinist says that it can't find blueprints anymore.

To get the capybara tests working I have to invoke some magic ...

To get transactional fixtures I'm forcing all activity onto a single transaction like this:

```
#always use the same connection so updates inside of transactions are visible.
#allows the use of use_transactional_fixtures
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.class_eval do
  def current_connection_id
    #always fetch the connection for the main thread
    # was Thread.current.object_id
    Thread.main.object_id
  end

  def clear_reloadable_connections!
    #do nothing, when connections are reloaded, otherwise the only connection is severed on each request
  end
end
```

After issuing something like
    `visit new_user_session_path`
I have to do this
    `load "#{Rails.root}/test/blueprints.rb"`
to be able to use my blueprints again.

Any ideas about how Machinist could lose its blueprints after a simple `visit`?

Comment: I am having a similar issue with Machinist blueprints after running a Rack test that uses `get`. Not sure what the cause is yet. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has got to do with RackTest driver for Capybara. After processing a request it is calling `ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup`! Looking at the comment on `ActionDispatch::Reloader`, it is only included when `config.cache_classes` is false.

So one solution would be to set `config.cache_classes` to true on `environment/test.rb` - but this is not the best solution.

Another solution would be to use another driver (I haven't tried this myself), Capybara comes with different drivers.

I've done something similar to Brad - by reloading blueprints on the my spec that uses Capybara visits. On your spec you can add an after block like:

```
describe "my test" do
    after do
        load_blueprint
    end
end
```

I put my the reload_blueprint method on a file in spec/support directory ie: `spec/support/load_blueprint.rb`

This still is a work around though and not a proper solution.

Comment: I'll try this out next week if i can find the time... and mark this answered if it works for me.